# Extremely slow windows 7 in virtual box on Ubuntu 16.04 host OS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine

I have installed Windows 7 on Virtual box. I have installed virtual box guest additions. My host OS is Ubuntu 16.04

My Windows is running extremely slow. It is often hanging so much that poweroff is the only option. The .Net Framework 4.5 took forever to install. My anti virus programs are simply refusing to install.

It may be noted that I have allotted 6 GB RAM to Windows and my total RAM caapacity is 12GB.

Comment: 1. How is the resource usage for your host when Windows starts slowing down?

Comment: 2. What are the settings that you have created for the guest os in virtualbox?

Comment: @NichlasH. No usge of guest OS, settings as usual

Comment: I don't understand. Your Windows 7 *is* the guest os. How much RAM have you allocated. How many processors? And how many processors/cores do your Host machine have?

Answer (score -1):

To make my Windows 7 virtual machine faster I gave it 2 processors, 3459 MB of base memory, and 128 MB of video memory. In addition, I enabled 2D and 3D acceleration,enabled VT-x/AMD-V, and Nested paging. Essentially I gave my Windows 7 VM max memory that was allowed, the max amount of processors allowed, and enabled both types of acceleration. Keep in mind though that this does make your host a little slower when you have the virtual machine on.

Hope that helps...